# YQL - return unread messages from YMail Inbox

Tags: yql, yahoo-api, yahoo-mail

I am trying to return the list of only unread messages from my Inbox folder from Yahoo Mail.

I am using this YQL `SELECT * FROM ymail.search  WHERE read="0"` - and this returns all unread messages.

But this YQL `SELECT * FROM ymail.search  WHERE fid="Inbox"` returns no results. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this

```
SELECT *
FROM ymail.messages
WHERE messageInfo.flags.isRead=0 
AND numMid=100
```

Where numMid = the total number you want to retrieve.

Comment: Nope, it's not working. I get completely the same result with:

`    SELECT *
    FROM ymail.messages
    WHERE messageInfo.flags.isRead=1 
    AND numMid=100`

Maybe there's some error in YMail engine? Or I am doing something wrong...?